# Call a JS function inside an XSL file

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, msxml

I got an XSL file where i have some JS code, like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:jscript="http://www.url.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl jscript">


<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="jscript">
function getCategoryLabel( elem )
{
    var s = "";

    s += elem.getAttribute("name");
    var oAnc = elem;

    oAnc = oAnc.selectSingleNode("ancestor(CATEGORY)");
    while ( oAnc != null )
    {
        s = oAnc.getAttribute("name") + " - " + s;
        oAnc = oAnc.selectSingleNode("ancestor(CATEGORY)");
    }
    return s;
}
</msxsl:script>
```

And i want to call the ***getCategoryLabel js function*** here on the html body created here :

```
<xsl:template match="//API">
        <html>
            <head>
                <xsl:element name="meta">
                    <xsl:attribute name = "charset">UTF-8</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <LINK HREF="API.css" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                //call the getCategoryLabel function here
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./CATEGORY">
                    <xsl:sort select="name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./NOTE">
                    <xsl:sort select="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

So can i call it ? If yes, how ?

***(I didn't precised but the msxsl script where the JS code is included is on the same file than the xsl code).***

Thanks again.

Comment: In an XPath expression inside of your XSLT code you can call `jscript:getCategoryLabel` if the processor supports the `msxsl:script` element. It is however not clear what you want to pass to the function when you call it and what you expect to receive on the JScript side and whether your used JScript code makes any sense, that depends on the processor and its API translation of XSLT/XPath types to platform or processor specific types.

Comment: My JS and XSL code are here just for the example. But how can i use this with an XPath expression, can you give me an example please @MartinHonnen ? Thanks again.

Comment: I found this example : ```<xsl:value-of select="jscript:getCategoryLabel(current)"/>```, it works the same way than a ```getCategoryLabel(this)``` with JS right ? @MartinHonnen

Comment: The official doc has an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256042(v%3Dvs.100)#xslt-file-scriptxsl

Comment: Do note, looking at your XSLT, you don't actually need to use a javascript function here. You can achieve your aim in pure XSLT, which is usually preferable as it wouldn't tie you to a particular processor like msxml. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you for that, by the way i got another question, i wanna use ```selectSingleNode``` and ```selectNodes``` and the xsl doesn't compile. I have that error when i try to use one of them : ```Code: 0x80020009
Microsoft JScript runtime error
This object does not handle this property or method
(the line is broken from the beginning of the script block).
Error returned by the method or property call.```. Is it normal ? Thanks again @MartinHonnen

Comment: I know, but i really need to use this JS function on my XSL file.. (this is just one function here but in reality i have 50+ functions, and recreate all of these in XSLT will take a lot of time). @TimC

Comment: Ask a question specific to that error with minimal but complete XML, XSLT samples to demonstrate it, together with exact information as to which XSLT processor and which version of it you use. So far it is not clear which XSLT processor you use, what kind of XSLT/XPath data you want to pass to JScript and which API you expect to use on the JScript side to handle the XSLT/XPath data. If you really use MSXML then as far as I remember, if you pass node(s) from XSLT to JScript, you receive an `IXMLDOMSelection` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757852(v=vs.85)

Comment: The standard aproach for extension functions is to register them in the XPath engine/XSLT processor by means of the API specification, not to embed an alien code into the stylesheet. The last one might slow down a transformation, wich is a fact in case of MSXML and `msxml:script`.